# Jquery limit for to enter character not work for IE/Chrome/safari

Tags: jquery

I have used the following jquery code to show how many character is left to type in textarea its work fine on all browser.
but when i use backspace and delete some character then its show how many character left fine on Mozilla but its not work for IE,Chrome,safari.

This is the demo link: http://jsfiddle.net/ckWNM/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var max = 10;
    $('textarea.max').keypress(function(e) {
        $("#counter").html("characters left : " +(10 - this.value.length));
        if (e.which < 0x20) {
            return;   
        }
        if (this.value.length == max) {
            e.preventDefault();
        } else if (this.value.length > max) {
            // Maximum exceeded
            this.value = this.value.substring(0, max);
        }
    });
}); //end if ready(fn)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the characters left on `keyup` as well can fix this in Chrome.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VZCJh/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var max = 10;
    $('textarea.max')
        .keypress(refreshAmount)
        .keyup(refreshAmount);
}); //end if ready(fn)

function refreshAmount(e) {
    $("#counter").html("characters left : " +(10 - this.value.length));
    if (e.which < 0x20) {
        return;   
    }
    if (this.value.length == max) {
        e.preventDefault();
    } else if (this.value.length > max) {
        // Maximum exceeded
        this.value = this.value.substring(0, max);
    }
}
```